Identify this UK TV Show about Time Travelling Team
I usually dislike these questions but here goes...
I watched a TV show where a team had the ability to time travel, but I seem to remember it was either unreliable technology.  Perhaps they only had a limited time and could only travel into the near past/future.
At one point I'm fairly sure one of the team tried to bring the lottery numbers home.  This is why I don't believe was Sliders.
I suspect it was on British TV around 1990-1995?

It might not be perfect fit, but another TV-show I remember involving travel through limited time is Seven Days. But there it was only one person and always exactly seven days into the past (and it was used by a government agency to prevent disasters and crimes). But given it may be too new and doesn't really fit, I'll rather leave it as a comment for exclusion of future answers. If it happens to be correct (which I don't think), I'll make it an answer.

By the way, any possibility to improve the title? I don't like ID-questions that much either, but even worse than an ID-question and a question including tags in the title is an ID-question with just the exact tag as completely irrelevant title. ;)

Thanks, I'll take a look and see.  I've done some research myself and I'm wondering about Crime Traveller but I'm not sure yet.

@ChristianRau very good point - done

Answering my own question (obviously you find it once you post the question).  I believe the series was Crime Traveller
